# can somebody explain how does the following code execute?

Tags: ruby

I am following a linked tutorial from the Odin project, its about blocks and procs in ruby. I can't quite understand how does the following code work.

```
class Array
  def eachEven(&wasABlock_nowAProc)
    # We start with "true" because arrays start with 0, which is even.
    isEven = true

    self.each do |object|
      if isEven
        wasABlock_nowAProc.call object
      end

      isEven = (not isEven)  # Toggle from even to odd, or odd to even.
    end
  end
end

['apple', 'bad apple', 'cherry', 'durian'].eachEven do |fruit|
  puts 'Yum!  I just love '+fruit+' pies, don\'t you?'
end

# Remember, we are getting the even-numbered elements
# of the array, all of which happen to be odd numbers,
# just because I like to cause problems like that.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].eachEven do |oddBall|
  puts oddBall.to_s+' is NOT an even number!'
end
```

Is `['apple', 'bad apple', 'cherry', 'durian']` a block in this context and are we calling the method `isEven` on that block?

Does isEven used to only return true or false and if true the following code will be executed?

```
do |fruit|
  puts 'Yum!  I just love '+fruit+' pies, don\'t you?'
end
```

Also, what is this line doing?

```rb
self.each do |object|
 if isEven
   wasABlock_nowAProc.call object
 end
end
```

If isEven is true then call `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` with the object??? What does calling that block with `object` mean?

Comment: If this tutorial is using naming conventions that are completely contrary to Ruby's strict `underscore_style` then I'm not sure this is a very good tutorial. This Ruby has a very strong JavaScript accent.

Comment: Please see "[“Explain X to me” questions: How to react?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271468/)".

Comment: Of note, the method `eachEven` does not _automatically_ iterates over the array. That is why it calls `self.each`: otherwise it would not iterate at all. A block does not imply iteration, even though block are commonly used when iterating, and are very useful tools when iterating. However, they have many other uses as well.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it in parts:

1)The class `Array` was native from ruby, which means we are adding a method to all instances of `Array`, the method is the `eachEven`.

2) This method receives as parameter a block to be executed, keep this information in mind.

3) The ["apple", "bad apple", "cherry"] is an instance from `Array`, which means that we can execute the method `eachEven` for this array:

```rb
array = ["apple", "bad apple", "cherry"]
array.eachEven do |something| 
# The do/end block is the parameter passed to the method `eachEven` 
# the block will be binded in `wasABlock_nowAProc` in this case
end
```

4) Inside the method `eachEven` we get the `self` (self is the array itself) and execute another method from the `Array` instance: `each` (this method iterate over the array binding the current position to the variable inside brackets: |object|)

5) If the condition returns a positive result, it will execute the block inside if, in the case:

```rb
wasABlock_nowAProc.call object
# We execute the block of step 2 passing the current position value as a parameter
```

In fact, if we execute the following code:

```rb
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array.eachEven do |position_value| 
  puts "The #{position_value} is even"
end
```

We gonna get the following result:

```
The 1 is even # The block `wasABlock_nowAProc` will bind the 1 to the object and print it
The 3 is even # Same here, 3 will be used as the object in the execution of `wasABlock_nowAProc`
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks i just have one last question. `wasABlock_nowAProc.call object` in here we are calling the do part of the Array with the object(the current value in the Array) as the parameter to the block. So in this case object is `oddball`? if so, why do we need to do that since the block itself is iterating over the array so we dont need to explicitly tell what value we are on.

Comment: "[“Explain X to me” questions: How to react?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271468/)"

Answer (score 1):

Let's break apart the code here:

```rb
['apple', 'bad apple', 'cherry', 'durian'].eachEven do |fruit|
  puts 'Yum!  I just love '+fruit+' pies, don\'t you?'
end
```

What we have here boils down to:

```rb
receiver.method do |block_argument_one|
  # this is the _body_ of the _block_
end
```

So:

- `['apple', 'bad apple', 'cherry', 'durian']` is called the *receiver* (or *subject*, or just *object* or *instance*)
- `eachEven` is the *method* being called on the *receiver*
- Everything from `do` to `end` is the block. It could also be `{` to `}` and work the same (well, [mostly](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#blocksclosuresandprocobjects))
- `|fruit|` is the block arguments list, with `fruit` being the only argument the block cares about.
- `puts …` is the body of the block

What happens to the block is:

1. The code in the block gets interpreted, but not run
2. A placeholder for that code is passed to the method the block is attached to
3. the method runs, and can access the block while running

Now lets look at how a method that takes a block works:

```rb
class SomeClass
  def some_method(regular_argument, &block_capture_argument)
    # method body

    # explicitly call the block:
    block_capture_argument.call("first value passed to block")

    # implicitly call the block (same as above)
    yield "first value passed to block"
  end
end
```

This shows several ways a block can be used:

When you define a method with the last argument beginning with `&`, a reference to the block is made available to the method by the name after the `&` (your `wasABlock_nowAProc` argument, for example). Then your method can do what is likes with the block, maybe calling it, or maybe even storing it somewhere a completely different method can use it.

Alternatively, you can use the `yield` keyword to call the block implicitly. In that case, you don't need a `&` argument to the method (but it still works if you do have that argument). Note that ruby allows you to attach a block to **any** method, regardless of if it uses that block. Methods can check if there was a block with the keyword `block_given?`, or check that the value of the `&` argument is present.

When you call the block, either with `yield` or with `call`, arguments you give to the call method are passed as arguments to the block.

The method can do **whatever it wants** with the block. It can call it once, twice, 0, or 300 times. It can call it with the same arguments each time or with different arguments each time.

In your specific example, the block gets called (with the value of `object`) for each item in the receiver, but only if the isEven variable is true.

Also in your specific example, you are calling the block from inside another block (which provides `object` for you), but don't let that confuse you.

To summarize:

- *blocks* can be attached to any method using either `do … end` or `{…}`
- blocks don't run unless the method they are attached to decides to call them
- *methods* get called on a *receiver*
- methods that use blocks get to decide how and when to use them
- methods that use blocks can call blocks (or use `yield`) and pass any number of *arguments* to the block.
- blocks can be defined to use those arguments (with the `|…|` syntax), and can name those arguments whatever they want (what matters is the order/position of the arguments).